# Right side content ceneter in all screen

Tags: html, css

I had faced problem in right content center of page.

my HTML page is 2 column page left column is Fixed (height 100% and width 350px ) and right side content width is 575px so i want to right side content center in all screen for example screen width is 1600px so its take right side content center in 1250px (1600px-350px.

Thank you advanced

Comment: Add the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: @mdesdev, the post isn't mine.

Comment: @user3364215 put content div in right side content and give it some width and `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a relative parent.

Have a container for right content, absolutely position it and apply `left` equal to the fixed width of the left div, and apply `right:0` to extend it to the remaining width.

Then simply make use of the old (*hence having more browser support*) `margin:0 auto` to position the content in center of right container div...

```
<div id='wrap'>
<div id='left'>one</div>
<div id='right'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#wrap {
 position:relative;
 height:100%;
}
#left {
 display:inline-block;
 width:150px; // in your case 350
 height:100%;
 border:1px solid;
}
#right {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:150px; // width of left content
 right:0px;
 height:100%;
}
#content {
 width:575px;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:1px solid;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/y3Kr6/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/md3Dp/5/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc
calc() is a native CSS way to do math. We can now set a dynamic width to the content column.
Desktop support for calc() is fairly ok. Added a fall back when calc() is not supported. Based on the max-width of 1600px of the parent added % width fall back.

```
html,body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}

.left {
width:21.875%;/* fall back */
width:-moz-calc(350px);
width:-webkit-calc(350px);
width:calc(350px);
float:left;
background:red;
}

.main {
width:100%;
max-width:1600px;
margin:auto;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.content {

width:78.125%;/* fall back */
width:-moz-calc(100% - 350px); 
width:-webkit-calc(100% - 350px); 
width:calc(100% - 350px);
float:left;
background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to calculate the width on the basis of screen resolution and then apply the width dynamically if you put the code here i can tell you the jquery code to how to apply the dynamically.

calculate the width on the basis of resolution you can get from this function in javascript:

```
window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left` property from right_content div and add the `text-align: center` on the parent div i.e right one div.

Comment: something misunderstanding my friend  i had require grey box center in all screen like if screen width is 1600px so right content is center of 1250px (1600px-350px)

your reply is really appreciate. 

Thank you